# How to display a custom number of runs in jenkins pipeline view

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins 2.73.3 and I always see last 10 runs displayed when I open my pipeline. Is it possible to display, for example only 5 or 20? where can I configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [their docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin) you should set up a system property `com.cloudbees.workflow.rest.external.JobExt.maxRunsPerJob` to something other than 10. This will affect all the jobs and requires a Jenkins restart, though.